# Drawing over a videoView after calling setZOrderOnTop(true)

Tags: android, android-videoview

The accepted answer for avoiding the black flicker on `VideoView` is to do something like the following. This works great, in fact it's smooth and I can reset the video, change the file and everything without a flicker.

Now...How can I draw a View on top of the `VideoView`?

```
mVideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

The order of the view on the layout makes no difference at all, since we are calling those methods.  I would love to show you guys a screenshot of what's going on but it's simply drawing the video over the other views.

Comment: The default Z-order, and the "media overlay" Z-order, are below the View layer. The "on top" Z-order is above. The only reason these would affect the way the video looked is if something were drawing opaque pixels on the View layer and obscuring the video surface.

Comment: It was the only way of getting rid of the black flash between video loops, or prior to the first playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate answering my own questions but here it goes:

The least painful way of doing this is actually to avoid using a `VideoView` and resulting to the use of a `TextureView` and playing the video in its surface. That way it doesn't necessarily try to be on top of everything but still allows us to draw things over it.

Comment: It is possible to achieve the same result but with better performance using a `SurfaceView` inside a `FragmentLayout`.

Comment: How are you setting zindex of textureview, I am not able to bring surace on above few views in custom dialog.